# Updating basefieldset inputfilters collide with collection fieldset object

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form

I’ve got a problem with my collections. I’ve been following the example tutorial (https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md#a-complete-example-using-zendform) and have succesfully made a `Blogpost` and `Tag` entity. In my controller I’ve an add action and edit action. My add and edit views contain the following code:

```php
<?php
echo $this->formElement($blogpost->get('addTag'));
$tag = $blogpost->get('tags');

?>
<fieldset id="tagFieldset">
    <?php
        echo $this->formCollection($tag);
    ?>
</fieldset>
```

The view has a button for adding tags dynamically (like in this example: http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.collections.html#adding-new-elements-dynamically), which works fine in the edit-action. When adding a new `Blogpost` with 2 tags at the same time, it only adds 1 `Tag` in the database (the count option is set to 1. When I increase this number, it is able to add tags according to the option). When I edit that `Blogpost` and add 2 tags (total of three), 2 tags are added to the database.

When debugging the addTags() function, the parameter holds only 1 Tag object at the add-action. In the edit-action it holds all the new tags that have been added (in my case, 2 new tags).

BlogpostFieldset look likes:

```php
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'addTag',
    'type' => 'button',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Add more tags',
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'addTag'
    )
));

$tagFieldset = new TagFieldset($serviceManager);
$this->add(array(
    'type'    => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
    'name'    => 'tags',
    'options' => array(
        'count'           => 1,
        'target_element' => $tagFieldset,
        'should_create_template' => true,
        'allow_add' => true,
    )
));
```

Javascript for adding fieldsets:

```js
$('#addTag').click(function(e) {
    var currentCount = $('form > #tagFieldset > label').length;
    alert(currentCount);
    //Set datatemplate (generated by the arraycollection)
    var template = $('form > #tagFieldset > span').data('template');

    //Replace the template to other addressfieldset
    template = template.replace(/__index__/g, currentCount);

    //Set new fieldset
    $('form > #tagFieldset').append(template);
});
```

It renders my templates correctly. Works fine in my edit-action, but my add-action only adds 1 tag. The problem exists in my controller by adding inputfilters or validators. In the case of adding a new tag I want to have some specific filters/validators.

The following code has been used to add the filter(s)/validators to the form/fieldset they have to been put on:

```php
public function addAction()
{
    $form = new Form($this->serviceLocator);
    $entity= new Entity();

    $form->bind($entity);

    if ($this->request->isPost()) {

        $data = $this->request->getPost();

        $form->getInputFilter()->get('fieldset')->get('input')->setRequired(true);
        $form->getInputFilter()->get('fieldset')->get('input')->allowEmpty(false);

        $form->setData($data);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
        // Handle the rest off this action.
        }

    }

    return array(
        'form' => $form
    )
}
```

When removing the following lines from the controller - `addAction()`:

```
$form->getInputFilter()->get('fieldset')->get('input')->setRequired(true);
$form->getInputFilter()->get('fieldset')->get('input')->allowEmpty(false);
```

It is able to add more `Tags` than the given option that has been set at the `count` of the `tagFieldset` that I've created.

Those inputfilters that I set in the `addAction()` are NOT on the collection fieldset. By addepting (with new inputfilters) my basefieldset, the collection fieldset is not able to add any more tags than the given `count` option. In this case it is useless to add anymore tagfieldsets with the Javascript function, since they will not be added.